# Net-SNMP: snmpwalk "timeout: No Response from localhost:1161" using Net-SNMP v5.4.3

Tags: linux, net-snmp

I'm new to Linux. I'm writing an SNMP extension agent using the MIB for Dummies (http://www.net-snmp.org/wiki/index.php/MIB_for_Dummies) config file (mib2c.mfd.conf). I successfully created my executable, adeSensorsTable, using my adeSensorsTable.MIB (mib2c util auto-generated the C source code from adeSensorsTable.MIB which I compiled into an executable). I then ran my executable:

./adeSensorsTable -f -L -DadeSensorsTable -M localhost:1161

I'd have a warning as I single stepped through the code:

iquerySecName has not been configured - internal queries will fail
Warning: no access control information configured.
(Config search path: /etc/snmp:/usr/share/snmp:/usr/lib/snmp:/home/ken/.snmp)
It's unlikely this agent can serve any useful purpose in this state.
Run "snmpconf -g basic_setup" to help you configure the adeSensorsTable.conf file for this agent.
[init_smux] bind failed: Permission denied

On a separate terminal I ran:
snmpwalk -v 1 -c public localhost:1161

adeSensorsTable terminal would return:

Connection from UDP: [127.0.0.1]:52684->[127.0.0.1]

Connection from UDP: [127.0.0.1]:52684->[127.0.0.1]

My snmpwalk terminal would return:
Timeout: No Response from localhost:1161

I'm not sure if snmp extension agent's warning is the show stopper in this case. I'd appreciate if someone could provide some pointers to my timeout issue. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added the following line to mine adeSensorsTable.conf config file:

> rocommunity public
>
> iquerySecName initial

then I won't get the timeout message and the snmpwalk request got to my snmp extension agent source code.

The "Connection from UDP:[127.0.0.1]:52684->[127.0.0.1]" message response from the SNMPD daemon was proper.